# Como evitar que uma propriedade seja mapeada em uma entidade no Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, propriedade, code-first

Preciso inserir uma propriedade na classe modelo,
mas quando eu insiro o code first, diz que a tabela já existe e foram feitas alterações.

Meu código:

```
public class Data
{        
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }

    //public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Se eu desmarcar a propriedade Selected ele dá esse error:

> The model backing the 'Context' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Tem como eu marcar essa propriedade para não gerar no banco?

Comment: Tem de fazer migrações no fim de alterar um `model`. É novo no asp mvc?

Comment: Tente utilizar a anotação `[NotMapped]` sobre a propriedade.

Comment: `[NotMapped]` funciona para campo calculado, é isso que ele quer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Entity Framework dispõe de dois modos de alterar a forma como a base de dados é configurada, **Annotations** ou **EF Fluent API**.

A primeira, consiste em anotar as propriedades das classes que definem os seus dados, a segunda, no *"overriding"* do método `OnModelCreating` da sua classe derivada de `DbContext.`

Pegando na sua classe seria assim:

**Annotations**

```
public class Data
{        
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]        
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent API**

```
public class SeuContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Data> {get; set;}
    .....
    .....
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Data>().Ignore(d => d.Selected);
    }
}
```

A utilização da `Fluent API` tem a vantagem de manter as suas classes "limpas".
Além disso, há certo tipo de configurações que não são possíveis de fazer através de anotações.

Veja [aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/data/jj591617.aspx) tudo o que pode fazer com a Fluent API.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou certo,

Answer (score 7):

Você pode fazer duas coisas:

- Marcar sua propriedade com o atributo `[NotMapped]` (recomendado):

```c#
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { set; get; }
    public string FirstName { set; get; } 
    public string LastName{ set; get; } 
    [NotMapped]
    public int Age { set; get; }
}
```

- Criar uma classe parcial da classe modelo que deve estar na mesma `namespace`:

```c#
namespace NamespaceDaClasseModelo
{
    public class partial NomeDaClasseModelo
    {
        public string NomeDaNovaPropriedade { get; set; }
    }
}
```