# O valor null se transforme automaticamente em 0

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou fazendo um cadastro de veículos, preciso que ele cadastre coloque que sempre que um veiculo for registrado o valor zero em vez de coloca o valor null, tentei por default, mas ele não grava a informação.

Estou usando SQL Server junto com o C# no visual studio.

Classe Controller:

```
public ActionResult Adiciona(VeiculoModel viewModel)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    Veiculo Veiculo = viewModel.CriaVeiculo();
    dao.Adiciona(Veiculo);
    //return View();
    return RedirectToAction("Form");
  }
  else
  {
    return View("Index", viewModel);
  }
}
```

Classe DAO:

```
public void Adiciona(Veiculo post)
{
  ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
  session.Save(post);
  tx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Como está sendo feita a inserção? Consegue colocar o comando que está sendo utilizado?

Comment: ainda não coloquei no meio da programação, mas tem umas inserções aqui que lhe mostra como funciona.

Comment: não entendo qual diferença faria, já que quando executar o select em uma variável numérica, se for null, ela virá zerada. a menos que esteja usando uma variável numérica que pode ser null (decimal?, double?, etc...)

Comment: é uma variavel numerico, no caso seria um integer, é que eu preciso que seja zero, pois em outra classe, ira comparar esse valor com um novo que ira sobrepor

Comment: exatamente....se é uma integer, nunca será null, sempre é inicializada com 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gere um `INSERT` usando `COALESCE` (ou `ISNULL`) que gere a query final:

```
INSERT INTO Veiculo(nome, valor)
VALUES('Gol', COALESCE(NULL, 0));
```

E, claro, altere a coluna para `NOT NULL`

---

Ou, transforme na aplicação ainda, de preferência no método `CriaVeiculo`:

```
veiculo.valor = this.valor ?? 0;
// ou
veiculo.valor = 0;
```

Comment: Isso seria para caso eu colocasse o registro do km na minha view, porém não irei coloca um campo para o registro manual, queria mais que quando você inserir os outros campos, como a numeração, modelo, essas coisas ira ser digitado manualmente, já o km não

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam Pode detalhar seu problema melhor? Se o valor não vai ser informado na View, então assegure com `veiculo.valor = 0` ou não entra ele no `INSERT`/`UPDATE`

Comment: Bem a minha view, terá 3 textbox, mas no meu bd terá quatro colunas, onde será o modelo,nº carro, ano e km, quero que ao registro o modelo, nº carro e ano será manual pelo usuario, depois de inserir esses 3 campos o km ficara como null, eu quero que de vez fique null, ele fique 0 para pode fazer a comparação com outra classe que vai chama ele como chave estrangeira

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo deu certo, eu so coloquei no controller, como uma variavel, deu tudo certo, obrigado

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam A maneira mais correta seria criar o default no banco e na aplicação não permitir que que seja gerado um `INSERT` incluindo a coluna `km` com valor `NULL`. O Entity Framework, por exemplo, pode se fazer como [descrito aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8013/como-evitar-que-uma-propriedade-seja-mapeada-em-uma-entidade-no-entity-framework)

Comment: A pessoa que deu o downvote por explicar o motivo para debatermos uma melhoria?

Answer (score 3):

Você também pode definir o valor do campo KM para 0, como default no SQL SERVER. Para isso, vá no Design de sua tabela, selecione o campo KM e defina o Default Value or Binding para 0

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

SQL SERVER:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAMPO,'VALOR') FROM TABELA
```